# Subplot of tables in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to create figure that contains several subplots which are tables. Let me try to explain what I am talking about. Below is a figure that has several subplots that are `imshow` plots. I want the exact same figure, but instead of `imshow' plots I want tables, just plain tables. In my example they would just display values 1 and 2:

```
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
```

How should I do this?

Thank You in Advance

[image]

Here is the code I used to generate the graph.

```
import pylab
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[2,1]])

fig = pylab.figure()

fig_list = []

for i in xrange(5):

    fig_list.append( fig.add_subplot(2,3,i+1) )
    fig_list[i] = pylab.imshow(x)


pylab.savefig('my_fig.pdf')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pylab.table command, documentation found [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.table).

For example:

```
import pylab
import numpy as np

x = [[1,2],[2,1]]

fig = pylab.figure()

axes_list = []
table_list = []

for i in xrange(5):
    axes_list.append( fig.add_subplot(2,3,i+1) )
    axes_list[i].set_xticks([])
    axes_list[i].set_yticks([])
    axes_list[i].set_frame_on(False)
    table_list.append(pylab.table(cellText=x,colLabels = ['col']*2,rowLabels=['row']*2,colWidths = [0.3]*2,loc='center'))

pylab.savefig('my_fig.pdf')
pylab.show()
```

I've also created an additional list variable, and renamed the fig_list, because the axes instance was being overwritten by the instance of the plotted object. Now you have access to both handles.

Other useful commands include:

```
# Specify a title for the plot
axes_list[i].set_title('test')

# Specify the axes size and position
axes_list[i].set_position([left, bottom, width, height])

# The affect of the above set_position can be seen by turning the axes frame on, like so:
axes_list[i].set_frame_on(True)
```

Documentation:

- [Axes API](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes)
- [Table API](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.table)
- [Table Example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I was looking for, though I don't really like the white space I end up having on top and bottom in every subplot. Still this looks like a workable solution.

Comment: ah, you can use `fig_list[i].set_frame_on(False)` to remove the axis frame. I've added that to the example. Also, you can use rowLabels and colLabels for labels of rows and columns.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. I have one question though, do you know how to give title to these tables? `set_title()` doesn't work for tables, do you know of some way to do it? Thanks Again.

Comment: `set_title()` should work on an axes instance. The axes documentation is at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes. Basically, an axes is a region inside the figure in which you plot artists (or another objects). Usually it's a line plot or similar, but in this case it's a table. Each table has it's own axes instance. `axes_list[i].set_title('test')` should work. Also, note the `set_position([left, bottom, width, height])` command can be used to change the size of the axes, which will bring the title closer to the table.

Comment: That's perfect! You really helped me. Thank You Very Much!